# SQL - Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pretty new to SQL and I am working on an assignment that requires me to find what movies were created by a company with "films" in its name based off the IMDB database.
A diagram of this database can be viewed here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9teB.png

This is the query I was working on.

```
SELECT t.title, t.id
FROM title t, movie_link m
JOIN movie_companies c ON (m.movie_id = c.movie_id)
JOIN company_name n USING (id)
WHERE n.name LIKE '%films%'
```

Comment: What is the error you get..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does seem to be somewhat close to what you'll need, but there are some weird things there. First of all, the implicit join here `title t, movie_link m` is performing a cartesian product between those tables. This code should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.title
FROM title t
INNER JOIN movie_companies mc
    ON t.id = mc.movie_id
INNER JOIN company_name cn
    ON mc.company_id = cn.id
WHERE cn.name LIKE '%films%'
```

There are several things that you need to take into account from that diagram to get the results that you want. For instance, since different companies can be the creator of the same movie (the diagram allows it), you'll need to use `DISTINCT` otherwise you might get duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a join predicate for the join between `title` and `movie_link` tables.

I recommend you NOT mix the "comma" and the "JOIN keyword" syntax in a statement. That is, remove that comma between `title` and `movie_link`) and replace it with the keyword `JOIN`. And add a join predicate, if you're not wanting a cross join.

Also, the `USING` syntax in the join predicate is a little ambiguous for my taste. I recommend you explicitly specify which columns from which tables you want to match, like you did for the join to `movie_companies` table.

The query below isn't runnable.  The ??? need to be replaced with appropriate identifiers and  aliases:

```
SELECT t.title
     , t.id
  FROM title           t
  JOIN movie_link      m ON m.???      = t.???
  JOIN movie_companies c ON c.movie_id = m.movie_id
  JOIN company_name    n ON n.id       = ???.???
 WHERE n.name LIKE '%films%'
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any need to join to the `movie_link` table at all

Comment: @Lamak: you may be right. There's a reference to `movie_id` from that table in a later join predicate. If that table isn't needed, the entire line containing "movie_link" can be removed from the query, and that join predicate that references the column can be modified. (I'd likely write the query backwards, starting with the company_name table as the first table in the FROM clause, and then add the join to each additional table.)